# Angular5 EC2 VPC deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy my application over Amazon EC2 instance,  I couldn't reach my application over the public IP address. Such as 34.54.23.22:4200:

- I've changed the security group and allowed TCP connection for port
  4200
- Nodejs is working fine, I've install it.
- Ng serve is working

My inbound rules :

> 80    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 
>   4100    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
>   443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
>   22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happen when you start ng serve

Comment: ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Comment: Did you added the port range 4200  inside the inbound section

Comment: yes I have added 4200 443 and 80

Comment: What did you select in the type dropdown menu, It must be HTTP.

Comment: I selected tcp with port 4200, if you select HTTP, it will not allow to change the port , it works with port 80

Comment: Exactly you sending a HTTP request over the Url , Please change the port for HTTP 80 to 4200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165753/discussion-between-lalit-onclick-and-melihcoskun).

Comment: there is no option in aws to change the port for security group http.default is 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the culprit is in how you do your `ng serve`. If you just did that command as is it won't work because you aren't allowing connections from the outside. For production deployment I highly recommend you use a true server like nginx or apache to serve your bundles (run ng build --prod).

To address your current situation you should be able to hit your page if you run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80` which will allow connections on port 80 from most anywhere. Just be sure your server has said port open as well.